# datepicker not working for dynamically created datepicker

Tags: html, jquery-ui

html:

```
<p id="drag11" class="ui-widget-content" > Calender </p>


    <div class="col-md-8"> <div id="droppable" class="ui-sortable" ><ol></ol></div></div>
```

jquery ui:

```
var calenderFieldCount++=0;
calenderFieldCount++;

 $("#droppable").append('<li class="ui-state-default">' +
 '<div class="cal" id="InputsWrapper_11' + calenderFieldCount + '">' +
 '<label class="cal"> calender:' + calenderFieldCount + '</label>' +
  '<p>' + '<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" name="mycal[]" />'+
 '<button class="removeclass11">x</button>' +
 '</p>' + '<br>' + '</div>' + '</li>');

$("#droppable").delegate(".hasDatePicker", "click", function () {
 $(this).datepicker();
});
```

when element with id= "drag11" is dragged and dropped in div with id="droppable" a textbox appears but when you click on the textbox the datepicker dose not appear. the above code is used. please help. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**try this jquery date picker just add field id and use js file**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
        $('#dob').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: using this code it generates a datepicker when the textbox is dropped. I want the datepicker only when the textbox is clicked and after choosing a date it should disappear.

Comment: hello,if you want to date picker on click just set your id on link or button.Give id(#dob) on link or button on which click you want DP.Ex: jQuery(document).click(function()